Maximalisation problem in $n$ variables
For nonnegative real numbers $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ such that $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n = n$ with $n \ge 2$ an integer, what is the maximum value of $x_1 + x_1x_2 + x_1x_2x_3 + \cdots + x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_n$ ?
The case $n=2$ can be solved using $AM-GM$ to obtain an answer of $\frac{9}{4}$, occurring at $x_1 = \frac{3}{2}$ and $x_2 = \frac{1}{2}$.
The case $n=3$ can be solved using Lagrange multipliers to obtain an answer of $4$, occuring at $x_1 = 2$, $x_2 = 1$ and $x_3 = 0$.
Any ideas how to generalize this problem for $n \ge 4$?

See how I dealth with the 2 and 3 variable case, and extend that to more variables. Theoretically, each time you're solving for the maximum of a one-variable polynomial, which you can use calculus. Though it's not immediately clear to me if a simple description exists.

Hello Calvin. I had a very similar idea for $n=2$ and $n=3$. I think you can solve my problem as follows. Let $f(n, c)$ be the maximum of the function as above in $n$ variables with sum $c$. We are interested in $f(n,n)$. Notice that $f(n,n) = x_1(1 + f(n-1, n - x_n))$. If we use recursion to find a general expression for $f(n, c)$ for any constant $c$, we can then calculate $f(n,n)$ in this manner.

Mathematica gives an answer of $\frac{305 + 13\sqrt{13}}{54}$ to the $n=4$ case, which in my mind is not indicative that $n \ge 5$ will go well.

Let $S_n $ denote the maximum value of the given expression. $S_4 = \frac{305+13\sqrt{13}}{54} $ with $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = \left( \frac{10}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{13}}{3}, \frac{5}{6} + \frac{\sqrt{13}}{6}, \frac{\sqrt{13}}{6} - \frac{1}{6}, 0 \right) $.  $S_5 = \frac89(9 +\sqrt6) $ with $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,x_5) = \left( 4 - 2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}, 1 + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}, \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}, 0, 0 \right) $.

It looks like as $n$ approaches infinity, the proportion of variables whose values are closer to 0 increases (when the maximum is achieved)
And OEIS found no such sequence

$n=6$ is already incredibly tedious to solve. Mathematica even gave up on finding the exact roots. (unlike $n=5$)

Thanks for the effort everyone. I'm assuming there won't exist a nice closed form and thus not a nice elegant method to solve this problem.
